How do I configure 2 public IP addresses on Debian and enable NAT traversal on one?
I got 2 IP addresses from my hosting company, xx.xx.xx.109 and xx.xx.xx.110, both in the same subnet. The subnet mask is 255.255.255.192 and the gateway is xx.xx.xx.20
I have a Proxmox server and would like to keep network access between management and VMs separate. So xx.xx.xx.109 would be used by the host and xx.xx.xx.110 would be used by VM guests to access the internet.
Due to my hosting company's rules all network traffic must come from a registered MAC address, so my VMs would need a private IP range (e.g. 10.0.0.x) and make use of NAT traversal to access the internet through xx.xx.xx.110.

What is the question? :)

Do you need / have any reason to configure them on different (v)NIC though?

@KonradGajewski how do I use 2 IP addresses on a single machine, and then configure the 2nd IP address for NAT traversal? But I think I should also ask if this is a good idea in the first place. Essentially what I want is to have all connections to the host dropped and only accessible with a VPN, and open all incoming/outgoing connections on the 2nd IP address which'd be used for my VMs.

@TomYan see my comment above, hopefully that clarifies my intent.

@WarningSign well, what I asked isn't related to your intent, but like the "environmental" requirements / limitations. If you and/or your hosting have no problem on having the two IPs configured on the same network interface, then it's just a matter of firewall rules. If for any reasons you need to have a dedicated interface for each IP, then very likely you'll need to set up policy routing (in addition to configuring the firewall).

Also, it sounds like you want some kind of (a "reverse" one, if I may) "kill switch" for traffics to the proxmox itself, and is worried that it would prevent access to/from the VMs, but traffics to/from the host itself and traffics that uses the host as a gateway/router (i.e., to the VMs) are governed by different "parts" (input v.s. forward base chain / hook) of the firewall, and the nat is governed by yet another part(s), before and after filtering depending on whether it's dnat or snat. (You question is really kind of broad, to be frank...)

It would be best for you to at least add the outputs of ip a ,ip r, iptables-save and nft list ruleset (and maybe also ip ru, just in case) to your post to give everyone a better idea of what's the "current situation". Then someone may be able to write you a ruleset or so for you to start with...

First things first - how many interfaces do you have connected to the hosting company?

@TomYan Ok I see, I wasn't sure what to make of that question as this is new territory to me. But thanks for the clarification, I will add the output of the commands you listed. There are no environmental requirements that force me to use different (v)NICs, the only requirement is that network traffic originating from my machine must use a MAC address assigned to me by the hosting company. Hence I'd have to reach for NAT traversal or a routed network configuration (but I'm not sure if a private IP range works with a routed configuration and I only have experience with NAT traversal)

@KonradGajewski I have 1 physical NIC with a single port connected to the host's network.

Ok, so in a nutshell, you need to configure IP aliasing - 2 IPs on one interface, and configure advanced routing + MASQ to channel traffic through a given interface based on its source IP.

Thank you @KonradGajewski I will look into IP aliasing
